# SPFx: Dropdown from 'office fabric ui react' is not working in yo sharepoint generator's latest version 1.6.0

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I have build a web part using SharePoint framework with SharePoint generator version 1.3.4 with dropdown multiselect=true in UI and then updated it to version 1.6.0 now the dropdown is not working. (Checkbox are not reflecting checked and unchecked actions in the UI).

`<div className={styles.column2}>
  <Dropdown label="Core Values" placeHolder="Select Core Values" options=   {this.state.coreChoices} multiSelect={true} selectedKeys={coreValues} onChanged={this.onCoreValueChange} />
</div>`

Can anyone help me out with this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the Dropdown and confirm that `this.state.coreChoices` and `coreValues` have valid values?

Comment: I have added this.forceUpdate() inside onCoreValuechange function. and it worked for me.